# How to implement toLower() if you get toUpper() already

Tags: c

Suppose you get the function `toUpper()` already, which is defined as `int toUpper(char)`,
How can you implement the function `toLower()`, which is `int toLower(char)`.
Thanks.

Comment: `toupper` and `tolower` are `int tolower(int)`, not `int tolower(char)`.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this is one way that uses the existing implementation of `toUpper` (note that `toLower` and `toUpper` are defined as eating `int` and I have done so accordingly; I am assuming that you have a typo in your OP):

```
int toLower(int c) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++) {
        if(c != i && toUpper(i) == c) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Edit: Thanks, [Chris Lutz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60777/chris-lutz).

Comment: @Chris Lutz: No, I don't think so. Please see the `if` condition.

Comment: My bad. Did you change it? I remember it differently, but I may just be not functioning (that's been happening today).

Comment: @Chris Lutz: I know the feeling; no worries. I originally had `upper == c && c != i` but changed it to `c != i && upper == c`.

Comment: Small changes: A) If you take out the variable `upper` and just put the `toUpper` call in the `if` statement, you short circuit and only have to call `toUpper` once or twice. B) `255` should be `UCHAR_MAX` for maximum portability.

Answer (score 2):

The only proper way I can see to do this is:

```
int toLower(int c)
{
    if(toUpper(c) != c) return c; // keep lowercase characters unchanged
    if(!isalpha(c)) return c;
    return c - 'A' + 'a'; // nonportable hack, only works for ASCII
}
```

Technically, the last line should be a full-blown `switch` statement, or something like:

```
static char lower[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
static char upper[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
// ...
return lower[strchr(upper, c) - upper];
```

Because the standard doesn't guarantee that alphabetical characters are consecutive in the character set. However, ASCII support is "good enough" for most people.

Comment: Don't know if your requirements require you not to use other standard library functions. If they do, then your requirements are most unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

Create two parallel arrays (A and B), each large enough to hold the entire character set. Step through all the values in A, and replace each value with `toUpper(value)`. Then step through B, and everywhere A differs, replace B[A[value]] with B[value] (i.e., everywhere `toUpper` replaced a value with an upper-case version, replace the upper-case version in B with the lower-case version from which it was converted). Once you're done, `toLower` just returns `B[value]` (and A can be discarded).

This assumes that you're dealing with upper/lower case that form a bijection (which, I should add, isn't always the case -- but I believe that assumption is implicit in the question).